# Upload images gallery to wordpress with python-wordpress-xmlrpc

Tags: python, wordpress, xml-rpc

Okay I have created a script in python using "python-wordpress-xmlrpc" package I am able to do everything except for uploading multiple images to wordpress and then adding them to gallery.

Here is my code to upload a single image file and then set as feature image:

```
fileImg = urlopen('image_url')
imageName = fileImg.url.split('/')[-1]
imageType = mimetypes.guess_type(str(fileImg.url))[0]

data = {
    'name': imageName,
    'type': imageType,
}

data['bits'] = xmlrpc_client.Binary(fileImg.read())

response = client.call(media.UploadFile(data))
attachment_id = response['id']
widget.thumbnail = attachment_id
```

Note: I know how to upload multiple files but i don't understand how to add those images in Product gallery.

Comment: hi, have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This technique worked for me:

```
attachment_id = response['id']
alt_value = "image alt"

sql = """INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES (%d,'_wp_attachment_image_alt','%s');""" % (int(attachment_id ), alt_value)
mycursor.execute(sql)
mydb.commit()
```